# Magento 2 image not found

Tags: magento2, css, less

I'm writing a callback module and when i try to insert image like following:

```
        a#popup-button{
        display: block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: url("../images/phone-icon.png") no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center center;
        font-size: 0;
    }
```

I get [image]

Comment: Did you run frontend deployment after adding image?

Comment: can you check if image is there in `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images`?

Comment: @MuhammadAnas no, but it's static

Comment: You need to run static deploy command, it will create a copy of image in required directory

Answer (score 0):

**once try with bellow code**

```
<img src="https://example.com/pub/media/social/whatsapp_new.jpg" style="margin: 0px 3px -5px 5px;" alt="call back">+91 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your image at below location

> magento_root\app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\web\images

Put below code into your `.css` file

```
body{
    background: url('../images/brushed_alu.png')top center;
}
```

Put `.css` file of your theme at below location

> magento_root\app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\web\css\style.css(your
>   .css file)

After that run below commands from your root directory of Magento

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```